# View Model deve ter classes relacionadas?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, asp.net-mvc-5, viewmodel

Tenho três entidades: `Manager`, `PersonalData` e `Address`. Um `Manager` possui um `PersonalData` e um `PersonalData` possui um `Address`.

Minha dúvida consiste-se no momento de criar as *ViewModels*, eu teria que ter dentro de `ManagerViewModel` uma propriedade do tipo `PersonalDataViewModel` e dentro de `PersonalDataViewModel` uma propriedade do tipo `AddressViewModel`?

Uma observação é que `PersonalData` é usada em outras entidades, como `Client`, `Supervisor`, pois é uma entidade que contém dados em comum como por exemplo, nome, telefone, e-mail, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*View models* representam dados que serão apresentados na *view*. Seu objetivo é montar um modelo que facilite o seu uso quando for apresentá-los, provavelmente cada um em um controle de tela diferente. Eles servem tanto para não usar tudo o que está no *model*, quanto para juntar dados de vários *models*. Podendo inclusive pegar dados que nem estão nos *models* usados. É comum que eles até já tenham dados "formatados" para a apresentação, oposto do que ocorre com o *model*.

Então deve se perguntar o que é mais adequado para sua apresentação, ter os dados colocados diretamente no objeto ou ter uma indireção para eles em outro objeto? Portanto ambos podem funcionar de acordo com a necessidade. A indireção pode ser para outro *view model* ou para um *model* diretamente.

Vai te ajudar ter os dados de `PersonalData` e `Address` em propriedades de `ManagerViewModel`? Ou basta ter algo que indique onde esses dados estão e a *view* consegue se virar bem assim? Lembrando que *views* devem ser muito simples e devem ter um processamento mínimo.

Eventualmente pode ter a indireção da propriedade e ter métodos auxiliares que ajudam acessar os dados dentro dessa propriedade.

Se estiver usando *view models* porque alguém disse que é bom, está usando pelos motivos errados. Use se ele facilita sua vida. Se for para reproduzir o que está nos *models*, então ele não tem função real para seu código.

*View models* podem ser atualizados automaticamente pelo *framework* por anotações ou eventos colocados nele, ou podem ser criadas pelo *controller*. Depende da necessidade. Elas podem atualizar os modelos também.

O importante é entender que o *view model* é um modelo para a visão. Ele trabalha para atender as necessidades da *view*, só isso importa.

Sabe a *view* do SQL? É basicamente isso (apesar da confusão de nomes). Você cria um modelo lógico mais fácil de consumir em uma situação específica.

[image: ViewModel]

Um [aprofundamento do tema](https://www.infoq.com/articles/View-Model-Definition).

Comment: Os dados de PersonalData e Address serão usados para o cadastro e edição de Manager. Por isso preciso deles na view, pois nos forms terei os campos para serem preenchidos. Daí a dúvida, criar somente uma view para Manager com todas as propriedades de PersonalData e Address ou ter nesta view duas propriedades que "apontam" para PersonalData e para Address.

Comment: Precisar é claro que precisa, se vai estar dentro dela ou não é que tem que decidir. Ninguém pode decidir por você. Te dei o parâmetro para decidir. O acesso indireto basta para facilitar para a *view*? Ou precisa estar tudo ali dentro para facilitar? Entenda para que serve um *ViewModel* para tomar a decisão certa. Ele deve representar o melhor modelo para a visão consumir de forma simples e fácil. Se quer saber como geralmente é feito, é desnormalizando, ou seja, colocando tudo dentro do próprio modelo da visão, mas sem sempre este é o caminho mais adequado.A necessidade da visão é que manda

Answer (score 3):

> Minha dúvida consiste-se no momento de criar as ViewModels, eu teria que ter dentro de ManagerViewModel uma propriedade do tipo "PersonalDataViewModel" e dentro de PersonalDataViewModel uma propriedade do tipo "AddressViewModel"?

É uma forma de fazer, mas não é estritamente necessária. Você pode usar uma *ViewModel* cujas propriedades sejam *Models*, se não houver necessidade de restringir alguma propriedade desses *Models*.

> Uma observação é que PersonalData é usada em outras entidades, como Client, Supervisor, pois é uma entidade que contém dados em comum como por exemplo, nome, telefone, email, etc.

A forma mais simples é não usando *ViewModels*. Usa-se *Models* com [`[Bind]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.bindattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) para evitar atribuição em massa, restringindo as variáveis críticas, se houverem. Ou seja, se alguma coisa não é preenchida em tela, ela não deve ser mencionada na decoração de `[Bind]`.