# Devo alimentar meu site pela API ou não?

Tags: laravel, api, arquitetura-de-software

Se eu estou desenvolvendo um site que possui uma API integrada, por exemplo, Laravel, possuo um site e uma API no mesmo projeto

Qual a melhor forma de alimentar o site?

- Devo criar um *controller* que irá buscar as informações da API em JSON e retornar o HTML?
- Devo criar um *controller* que irá buscar as informações direto do banco (fazendo assim com que eu tenho que talvez repetir código no controller da API e do site)

Comment: Se o *controller* já está no mesmo servidor que o banco, não vejo porquê fazer uma requisição extra para buscar os dados na API.

Comment: Eu imaginei o mesmo, mas ai eu tenho que optar entre fazer uma requisição extra (que é feita direto do servidor, então nao sei se faz tanta diferença) ou repetir o código em dois lugares diferente, o que dificulta a manutenção

Comment: E se a API já fornece todos os dados, por quê precisa de um controlador? Não pode fazer a aplicação se servir direto na API?

Comment: Sim, mas a API fornece informações separadas, por exemplo, pessoas, produtos, marcas, se eu for fazer uma página que carrega os 3, eu preciso ou carregar por ajax, ou fazer uma outra função que chama as 3 requisições

Comment: API com site integrado ainda é muito confuso para mim

Comment: E por quê, então, não definir um *Service* que fornece os dados tanto para o controlador quanto para a API?

Comment: hmmm, interessante, não conheço muito sobre service, vou dar uma pesquisada nisso então, obrigado @AndersonCarlosWoss

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Qual atende melhor a sua necessidade? Use essa. E só você pode responder isso.

Hoje há uma tendência ao uso de API e usar um *frontend* web que consome essa API igual um *frontend* desktop ou mobile, ou algum serviço faria. Isso tem lá sua utilidade, e em alguns casos é o melhor a fazer, especialmente quando é uma aplicação web e não um website. Ainda que eu seja, de forma geral, um crítico da aplicação web, na maioria dos casos, ou não deveria ser uma aplicação ou não deveria ser web. Falo do *frontend*.

Se for um website geralmente a abordagem tradicional de trabalhar com a renderização do formato da página ser feita no servidor pela *view* do MVC ou outra forma.

Nesse caso não tem porque ter uma camada extra. Só a *view* deve ser diferente, uma gera JSON e a outra gera HTML. Se precisa de um *controller* diferente, ou está fazendo algo errado ou está usando uma tecnologia rígida que não atende bem a necessidade.

Repetir o código em dois lugares não deveria ser opção. Mesmo que a tecnologia e/ou arquitetura não permita, ainda pode abstrair a execução em funções em um serviço separado.

Idealmente o controlador deveria atender bem ambos, se for complicado, pelo menos faça ele atender sua real vocação que é entregar o dado para a *view*.

Eu vejo muita gente escrevendo que a lógica da aplicação deve ser toda ali. Até eu mesmo devo ter escrito isto em algum momento. Mas pensando bem, isso está errado, o *controller* deve ser a lógica de comunicação do modelo com a visão. Execução que não deve estar no modelo, deve estar em uma parte específica que está ligada ao controlador, mas não diretamente. Claro que se é simples, não tem utilização em mais de um lugar, não é errado embutir ali mesmo.

Tenha em mente que as *actions* do controlador é definido por como recebe os dados e como os manda, não é o processamento dos dados. Não diretamente. Aí não tem repetição, muito menos fere o DRY. Use um serviço.

Se a API é mais baixo nível e o *frontend* é mais alto nível, é só usar os bloquinhos de Lego soltos na primeira, e juntá-los na segunda. Por isso que o processamento deve ser separado, quando precisa.

## A arte perdida de abstrair

Hoje as pessoas estão tão preocupadas em seguir <strike>receitas de bolo</strike> padrões, fazer <strike>maluquices que ela não entende</strike> arquitetura, que esquecem do básico do básico, do fundamento.

Existem 3 coisas que revolucionaram a programação:

- A escrita de código em alto nível
- A modularização
- O gerenciamento automático de memória

O segundo em sua essência é saber usar funções para seu benefício, para evitar repetições e alcançar o [DRY](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120931/101).

Hoje grande parte dos códigos não atendem isso, muitos experientes sequer percebem isso. A organização do código é mais importante que seguir o mestre. Entender o nível correto de abstração te ajuda mais que decorar modelos prontos que talvez não seja o mais adequado para seu problema.

Por exemplo, inicialmente existia o ASP.NET MVC e o ASP.NET WebAPI. Feitos pelos melhores engenheiros do mundo. Demorou para perceberam que era tudo repetido e aí fizeram o ASP.NET Core para resolver isso.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Linda resposta, eu evito ao máximo repetir código o meu problema é saber onde devo colocar cada código (isso no laravel), se eu faço um select de pessoas que traz também o endereço delas, muitas vezes nao sei se devo fazer isso direto no controller ou fazer uma função no model, mesmo que eu não busque pessoas junto com endereço mais de uma vez

Comment: Obrigado. No model vai ao que se refere ao objeto, no *controller* vai oque precisa controlar a a comunicação das camada e eventualmente algo que precisa processar antes de ir para um lado ou para outro.

Comment: Ou seja no meu caso eu devo fazer o select com o join no model, e no controller organizar essa e outras informações para retornar a view?

Comment: Depende, mas é possível, Aí talvez seja o caso de ver isto: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/305207/101