# No MVVM uma ViewModel pode conhecer mais de um model?

Tags: mvc, arquitetura-de-software, mvvm, viewmodel

Na arquitetura MVVM, uma *viewmodel* pode "conhecer" várias *viewmodels*.
E no caso da relação VM-M? Uma *viewmodel* pode "conhecer" vários *models* diferentes?

Ex:

```
CreditCardViewModel

--> Model CreditCard

--> Model BusinessInfo

--> Model UserRegister
```

Ou cada *viewmodel* deve ter sua responsabilidade e eu ter que chamar o método dela quando eu quero um resultado resultado específico?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A dúvida é legítima, mas fico pensando como ela surgiu. Será que é porque as pessoas criam tantas regras que sempre surge a dúvida se tem uma regra pra isso? O que achei mais curioso é saber uma parte da resposta.

Eu sou contra regras, sou favorável em entender o que está fazendo, aí pode até surgir uma regra pessoal, com suas devidas exceções se for pertinente (nem sempre é pertinente ter regras mesmo pessoais). Então por que deveria ter uma regra que diz isto? Isto é importante saber e pode dar a resposta.

Já demos algumas respostas sobre o assunto:

- [O que é MVP e MVVM?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21539/101)
- [Pra que serve uma ViewModel no ASP.NET MVC?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/305207/101)
- [View Model deve ter classes relacionadas?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/140339/101) (acho que a mais importante)
- [Diferença entre DTO e ViewModel?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/305301/101)
- [MVC versus MVVM](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/214658/101)

Podemos ver que o motivo de existir esse elemento na construção do software é justamente juntar vários modelos. Não só isto, pode ser pegar partes de um modelo, ou pode pegar só um modelo. Mas chega ser quase sacanagem se pegar um modelo e reproduzi-lo no *viewmodel*, não que não possa ou não deva, tem que fazer por padronização, mas é um código que não faz nada útil, e se praticamente todos seus modelos são iguais aos modelos de visão então talvez sua aplicação não deveria ter adotado isso a não ser por obrigação de arquitetura adotada (o que evidencia que foi uma adoção errada, ainda que em alguns casos não tenha como escapar dela).

Agora, se vai fazer certo é outra questão. Não quer dizer que toda *viewmodel* deva conhecer vários modelos. Quais fazem sentido ser assim será definido dependendo do que está resolvendo. Por isso é preciso entender para que serve a *viewmodel*, se o que quer fazer atende bem o que ela se propõe então pode e até deve fazer, se fizer sentido naquilo. Colocar vários modelos em uma *viewmodel* sem precisar é errado, e isto deveria ser óbvio. Se é possível colocar vários modelos na *viewmodel* eu é que pergunto, por que não colocar, se fizer sentido para o problema? E qual seria a solução então? As perguntas são retóricas, é que não vejo como poderia ser diferente, depois de se saber o que é uma VM.

Comment: Muito Obrigado pela resposta.
De fato, foi uma decisão externa que me levou a me perguntar sobre os fundamentos que justificasse essa tomada de decisão, a não ser a divisão de responsabilidade de cada viewmodel, como se o fato dela usar recursos diversos fosse impedi-la de exercer sua função! 
Muito pelo contrário, auxilia...

Como eu me perguntava se isso fazia sentido ou não, resolvi fazer a pergunta. 
Mas como dizem, manda quem pode, questiona quem tem discernimento, e obedece quando a situação é irredutível... Deixa eu apagar uns incêndios aqui.

Comment: Sim, já dava pra perceber algo assim na pergunta. Você tem alguns subsídios para tentar argumentar de novo, e pode achar outros seguindo o que obteve agora.

Comment: E creio que a pergunta deixa no ar, o tom de "posso ou não posso ", quando na verdade a sua resposta responde muito bem. Faça mas se você realmente não tem outra forma de fazer! Ótima resposta @Maniero.

Comment: @RicardoLucas Na verdade eu acho que isto deveria ser fácil decidir entendendo o que é uma *viewmodel*, me surpreende algumas pessoas terem dúvidas sobre isto (considerando que ela resolver usar uma VM sabendo  o que é, e se adotou sem saber isto então tudo já está errado e nada mais importa), pior ainda é a pessoa saber o que é uma *viewmodel* e decidir que ela não possa ter vários modelos. Pelo jeito a pessoa só faz CRUD **extremamente** simples.